# Display data from database via a table based on search criteria

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, react-hooks, react-router

I have a `form` in which there are multiple fields. The user can enter in any of the field and submit it to the `database`. I then display display this data in the `table`.

I have created backend `APIs` and they are working properly. I also know how to create a `component` on `react`, but I am not able to figure out how to display the `data` in the `table` after the search button is pressed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look at controlled input in React. Basically you need to update the state and use the state value in React for the value of the input

Comment: Thanks Ali, can you please give me some snippet?